# Solve infinite series equation with logarithmic terms.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Solve logarithmic equation: $$\frac{\log x^2}{\log^{2}x}+\frac{\log x^3}{\log^{3}x}+\cdots+\frac{\log x^k}{\log^{k}x}+\cdots=8$$

here $\log$ is assumed to have base $10$.

So far I managed to rewrite it as: $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n}{\log^{n-1}{x}}=8 \iff \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n\log_{x}^{n-1}{10}=8$$

But I don't know how to find the infinite sum.

Comment: Shouldn't it be:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{\log^{n} x}=8$$
Based upon the order of the polynomial in the numerator equaling the power of the logarithm in the denominator?

Comment: No, in the numerator he used $\log x^n=n \log x$ and canceled one power of the log.

Comment: I think it's good so far.

Comment: $\frac{\log x^2}{log^{2}x}=\frac{2\log x}{log^{2}x}=\frac{2}{\log x}$ The rest follows by analogy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nf^{n-1}(x)=\frac 1{(1-f(x))^2}$$

Now you say that you have rearranged your equation as:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty n\log_x^{n-1}10=8$$

So you now have to solve the equation:

$$\frac 1{(1-\log_x10)^2}-1=8$$

Rearranging the terms leads us to:

$$\log_x10=\frac 23$$

Which solution is: $10\sqrt {10}$

Comment: I don't know the thing you said "we know". How did you get that? I mean, why is that so?

Comment: No, the answer is okay.

Comment: I agree the answer is OK (I was using base $e$ logarithms).

Comment: The first line comes from generating functions, we know that $\frac{1}{1-z}$ has the power series expansion $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$.  Then, its derivative is $\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n-1}$.  Then, we can substitute anything we'd like for $z$

Comment: @lemniscate all of the answers to this use this fact. Without it, you're pretty out of luck to solving it. Do you have some kind of context where this came up which makes you believe that one shouldn't use the calculus methods?

Comment: Because it popped out in elementary mathematics book...

Comment: @leminscate can you provide the exact reference?

Comment: @AdamHughes Yes I can, though I don't see the point. [Here it is](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/277021240_Zbirka_zadataka_za_pripremnu_nastavu_iz_matematike_IV_izdanje) .

Comment: @lemniscate mostly because in all my time as a mathematician, I have yet to see a series like that asked in a context without at least a series level background (which is most frequently developed in second-semester or similar calculus). It would help a lot to see exactly how whatever author has developed the material to make this question accessible without the standard approach.

Comment: @AdamHughes This book serves as a preparatory course for admission test preceding the enrollment to university. It contains only problems, and partly solutions for some of them, as for the theory background it relies solely on student's knowledge gathered in high school, therefore providing no theory in itself. High school curriculum mentions arithmetic and geometric progressions briefly, and gives only formulas for certain problems, no proofs included.

Comment: @lemniscate then the geometric series could still get the formula we're all using, namely that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}={1\over (1-x)^2}$$

by using recursion/induction on power series methods, so this is still probably the intended solution.

Comment: @lemniscate in particular you can see from basic methods that

$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nx^n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k+j=n}a_kb_j\right)x^n.$$

Then by choosing $a_n\equiv 1$ and $b_n\equiv 1$, we see that

$$\sum_{k+j=n}1\cdot 1=n$$

since there are $n$ ways to write $n=k+j$, namely $1+(n-1), 2+(n-2),\ldots (n-1)+1$.

Comment: @lemniscate I edited my answer to have this explanation included for the level you're looking at. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Observe: Since
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n}{\log^{n-1}(x)}=8,
$$
we know that by multiplying by $\frac{1}{\log x}$, we have
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n}{\log^{n}(x)}=\frac{8}{\log x},
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n}{\log^{n-1}(x)}-\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n}{\log^{n}(x)}=8-\frac{8}{\log x}.
$$
Next, by reindexing the second sum, we have
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n}{\log^{n-1}(x)}-\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{n-1}{\log^{n-1}(x)}=8-\frac{8}{\log x}.
$$
Canceling in the sums we have
$$
\frac{2}{\log x}+\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{1}{\log^{n-1}(x)}=8-\frac{8}{\log x}.
$$
The remaining sum is a geometric series (and assuming $|\log x|>1$), we have
$$
\frac{2}{\log x}+\frac{1}{\log^2 x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\log^{n}(x)}=8-\frac{8}{\log x}.
$$
Simplifying the geometric series, we have
$$
\frac{2}{\log x}+\frac{1}{\log^2 x}\frac{\log x}{\log x-1}=8-\frac{8}{\log x}.
$$
Writing $y=\log x$, we have
$$
\frac{2}{y}+\frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{y-1}=8-\frac{8}{y}.
$$
Clearing fractions, we have
$$
2(y-1)+1=8y(y-1)-8(y-1).
$$
Simplifying, we know that
$$
0=8y^2-18y+9.
$$
Applying the quadratic formula, we have
$$
y=\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{2}.
$$
Since, we assumed earlier that $|y|>1$, it follows that 
$$
\log x=\frac{3}{2}
$$
or that
$$
x=10^{3/2}.
$$
This answer checks with wolfram alpha.

Comment: Sorry I haven't cleared that out right away, but the base of log is 10.

Comment: The only change was in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=10^{y}$. Then we have

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty ny^{1-n}$$

Setting $t=y^{-1}$ we get

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty nt^{n-1}={1\over (1-t)^2}-1.$$

We can see this formula is true because when multiplying two power series, $\sum a_nx^n, \sum_nb_nx^n$ we get the coefficient of $x^n$ is $\sum_{k+j=n}a_kb_j$ and

$$\sum_{k+j=n}1\cdot 1=n$$

since there are $n$ ways to write $n=k+j$, namely $1+(n-1), 2+(n-2),\ldots (n-1)+1$.

Setting this equal to $8$, we get $(1-t)^2={1\over 9}$, i.e.

$$1-t=\pm {1\over 3}.$$

Then this means

$$t={3\pm 1\over 3}\iff y= {3\over 3\pm 1}$$

$|y|>1$ for this to converge, so $y=3/2$.

So $x=10^{3/2}=10\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: the sum in the question starts with $n=2$